# SSIS - 'Cannot insert the value null' even though Identity Column is set

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm importing CSV contents into a database table using SSIS. The destination table has a Sequence column that is PK and is also Identity Column that is set to auto increment.

I am ignoring both source and destination column that would do the mapping between these because I'm expecting to auto increment the destination column when I execute the package, however it does not.

I do have the 'Keep Identity' checked in the ole db destination. Any ideas?

Comment: What do is it mean by this sentence::"Cannot insert null even though id column is set "..are you trying to insert into a table with identity column...

Comment: This sentence contradicts with your title:  "  I am ignoring both source and destination column that would do the mapping between these because I'm expecting to auto increment the destination column  "

Comment: By that I mean I've set its 'is Identity' to Yes, and 'Identity Increment' to 1, and 'identity Seed' to 1.

Comment: Basically, in SSIS, i'm leaving out Column 0,  and the destination column(Sequence), during mapping, I'm ignoring it so it doesn't map to anything. I'm expecting upon package execution, it would insert into Sequence automatically because it is an Identity column with auto increment set to 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have keep identity to false (un-checked).  When this is true it is expecting you to insert the value and asking the DB engine to not auto increment during this operation.